# Why does $e^x+e^{-x}-4$ equal $e^x-e^{-x}-4$ on this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm asked to find the intercepting points of two equations $y=4-\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$.

Putting them together and opening the brackets I get $e^x+e^{-x}=4$.
(My textbook gives $e^x-e^{-x}=4$ as an answer to this step.)

I continue to substitute $t=e^x$ and turn my own equation into $t+1/t=4$, then I proceed to solve for $t$ through expanding the first term by $t$ and creating a perfect square $(t-2)^2=3$, which in turn gives me $t=2\pm\sqrt{3}$. Now I can substitute $e^x$ back into the equation and get the points $x_1=\ln(2-3^{1/2})$ and $x_2=\ln(2+3^{1/2})$. To my surprise these are the same points that are listed in my textbook, even though the textbook uses $e^x-e^{-x}-4$ instead of $e^x+e^{-x}-4$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You can find a guide to formatting math with mathjax here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: use the correct format

Comment: verify the title of your OP, it leads to a different result from the detailed OP

Comment: The title has one equation, the body of the Question refers to "the intercepting points of two equations" but does not clearly identify those.  The expressions in your first line are not equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve
$$
4-\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
$$
the equation is indeed $e^x+e^{-x}=4$ and your solution seems correct; with $e^x=t$, it becomes
$$
t+\frac{1}{t}=4
$$
or
$$
t^2-4t+1=0
$$
whose roots are $2+\sqrt{3}$ and $2-\sqrt{3}$, as you found.

There is no way the equation can be rewritten as $4=e^x-e^{-x}$. There seems to be a typo in your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Note that following the answer posed in the title we have

$$e^x+e^{-x}-4=e^x-e^{-x}-4\iff e^{-x}=-e^{-x}\iff e^{-x}=0$$

which is never true.

Since we are dealing with

$$4-\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})
\iff 8-e^x-e^{-x}=e^x+e^{-x}\\\iff e^x+e^{-x}=4\iff e^{2x}-4e^x+1=0$$

and by $t=e^x$ we obtain

$$t^2-4t+1=0\implies t=e^x=2\pm\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, as you also figured out, $$e^{x}+e^{-x} = 4 \implies x = \ln(2 \pm \sqrt{3}).$$
Second, considering $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$e^{x}-e^{-x} = 4 \implies x = \ln(2 + \sqrt{5}).$$
So there might be some typing mistake in the book solution.